# How to loop through delimited string returned by jQuery AJAX request

Tags: ajax, jquery

So the following jQuery is posting some values to a PHP script and getting back a comma delimited string:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "_js/changetags.php",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){

        arr = data.tagsinserted.split(',');

        $.each(arr, function(n, val){
            // toggle here
        });
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is place the following code into the loop, so that the value of the delimited string is used to toggle a class on/off:

```
$("#id_"+delimitedvalue).toggleClass("off on");
element.toggleClass("off on");
```

The result is that a whole batch of elements on the page are toggled on/off together if the AJAX request was successful.

But I can't get the code to work. I don't know how to assign the returned delimited values to the toggle function. Also I suspect there is there a better way to do this and would love to hear any ideas!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "_js/changetags.php",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        var arr = data.tagsinserted.split(',');

        for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            //Bad idea to use .each(), much slower in this case
            $("#id_"+arr[i]).toggleClass("off on");
            element.toggleClass("off on");
        }
    }
});
```

Also, we could help more if you gave us an example of what `changetags.php` is responding with...

Comment: changetags.php is responding with a pure delimited string as output by the HTML - e.g. 3,5,6,7,9,12

Comment: Sorry to ask such a basic question, but how do I check what is being returned by the PHP (just to eliminate this as a problem). Is there a way I can print the string on screen.

Comment: Yes - `success: function(data){ alert(data) }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$.each(arr, function(n, val) {
    $('#id_'+val).toggleClass('off on');
});
```

Comment: Very bad idea to use `.each` in this case, much slower than using a `for` loop...